# Toyota camry 2003 front seat stuck forward

Tags: toyota, camry

How do I pop off the side panel of the font seat, because it is stuck forward and won't move? 2003 Toyota Camry.

How do I get the seat to go back so I can drive it?

Comment: Electric or manual seat?